# Input/output error

Tags: docker, phpstorm, virtualbox, docker-volume

I create file and show its contents inside of virtual machine using Docker:

```
touch file.txt
docker run \
    --rm -it \
    --volume $(pwd):/app \
    --workdir /app \
    alpine:3.6 \
    sh -c '\
        while : ; do \
            cat file.txt ;\
            sleep 1 ;\
        done \
    '
```

Then I change file locally:

```
date > file.txt
```

Everything is ok.

But when I change file in PhpStorm, I get an error message for about 20 seconds:

```
cat: can't open 'file.txt': I/O error
```

What is possible reason of this behaviour and how can I diagnose it?

(Docker 17.10, VirtualBox 5.1.30, PhpStorm 2017.2.4)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is happening here (not a Docker or Linux person) .. but try disabling "safe write" option in PhpStorm settings. With that option enabled IDE first writes into a temp file (e.g. `file.__temp_jb__`) and only then renames into the target (`file.txt`). Maybe that somehow conflicts with your script...

Comment: Oh, thank you, it worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling "safe write" option in PhpStorm settings: `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings --> Use "safe write"...`

With that option enabled IDE writes into a temp file first (e.g. `file.__temp_jb__`) and only then renames it into the actual target (`file.txt`).

It looks like such manipulation (original file gets deleted and replaced by another one) somehow conflicts with your script.